# where to put vendor-modules translation dictionaries?

Tags: magento2, localisation

I am using **Magento 2.0.4** and want to provide translation dictionaries to vendor modules such **`vendor/magento/module-customer`**

I have successfully collected the phrases of this module, but don't know where I should put the **`.csv`**

Note: I am not going to install a language package, I'm translating each module in isolation.

Comment: See for example the Magento [Customer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/i18n) module.

Comment: @SteveJohnson I have placed translations inside app/code/Magento/Customer/i18n/ but it doesn't load! Moreover, I didn't find this app/code/Magento folder and its subfolders and created them myself

Comment: In the Magento 2 GitHub (and if you clone GitHub), you'll see `app/code` but if you installed via archive or Composer, you'll see modules under `vendor/<vendorname>`. You should put your `.csv` file under the appropriate directory, which in your case, sounds like `vendor`

Comment: According to our docs, translations for this module should go to: `vendor/magento/module-customer/i18n/`. What is the name of your .csv file? It must use the correct language code in the naming, to be applied correctly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From @steve-johnson comment:

In the Magento 2 GitHub (and if you clone GitHub), you'll see app/code but if you installed via archive or Composer, you'll see modules under vendor/. You should put your .csv file under the appropriate directory, which in your case, sounds like vendor

Comment: This is a bad answer! As soon as you update the module your translation is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue..
After hours of investigating i found out that this is the closest to a solution that accually works. It's translates per vendor, so then I don't have to have all phrases in one large file.

Create:

```
/app/i18n/vendor/de_ch/de_CH.csv
/app/i18n/vendor/de_ch/composer.json
/app/i18n/vendor/de_ch/language.xml
/app/i18n/vendor/de_ch/registration.php
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2

Comment: great tip making a i18n pack per vendor saved me a lot time were the vendor has a tun of modules

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep **`.csv`** file inside your theme i18n folder.

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/i18n/
```

Remove var folder and check.

Comment: I am pretty sure these answers are incorrect but am checking. I believe that a module translation file goes with the module. We'll post an update ASAP.

Comment: You have to put i18n folder inside your theme and inside i18n folder keep your csv for changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep **.csv** file inside your theme i18n folder.

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/i18n/
```

Comment: why it should be under the theme folder? I'm translating a module not creating a theme!